# Func<string> DoSomething: Type [...] Controller+<>c__DisplayClass0_0 is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, objectcache

I'm trying to implement FileCache (https://github.com/acarteas/FileCache) which is based on ObjectCache.
I'm trying to check a cache object for its existence, or add it if required and return. When the object does not exist however, the delegate is not executed and an error is thrown: Type 'myNamespace.Controllers.ListController+<>c__DisplayClass0_0' in [...] is not marked as serializable.

What I've tried (simplified):

```
private string generateString(int? Id)
{ 
    return "String";
}

public ActionResult GetSomething(int? Id)
{
    var cacheFilePath = $"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}{"\\cache"}";
    var cache = new FileCache(cacheFilePath, false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    if (purgeCache)
        cache.Remove($"CacheKey{Id}");

    Func<string> createString = () => generateString(Id);

    var myString = (string) cache.AddOrGetExisting($"CacheKey{Id}", createString, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(30) });
    return new JsonStringResult(myString);

}
```

Ok, now I've tried to specify the delegate createString with Serializable, but that doesn't work.
Could someone point me into the right direction?

Essentially I want:
- run a statement that returns a previous output of generateString(123); if it doesn't exist or is expired, it should re-generate it.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the nature of `FileCache`, I think the only reasonable way to do that is to fallback to the usual way - check if item exists in cache and if not - add it:

```
private static readonly _cacheLock = new object();
private static readonly FileCache _cache = new FileCache($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}{"\\cache"}", false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
/// ...
lock (_cacheLock) {
    var myString = _cache.Get($"CacheKey{Id}");
    if (myString == null) {
        myString = generateString(Id);
        _cache.Set($"CacheKey{Id}", myString, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(30) });
    }
}
```

Lock is necessary because `FileCache` both writes and reads from the same file, and this is never safe to do from multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks Evk. Pity you removed the previous answer, I've learned a lot from it. I think I'll mark this as accepted. Quite odd that it doesn't work as I would expect; I thought this would be quite desirable for a quick and easy caching mechanism.

Comment: Well it was wrong (for FileCache) so I could not leave it. And I think it's hard to implement this in any other way when cache is represented by a file. So even if it worked like you expect - internally I think it would work similar to this. You can always add an extension method that will accept delegate and run code above, if you want a clearer syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `AddOrGetExisting` says the second parameter is `object value` and not a callback delegate:

https://github.com/acarteas/FileCache/blob/master/src/FileCache/FileCache.cs

```
public override object AddOrGetExisting(string key, object value, CacheItemPolicy policy, string regionName = null)
```

I think you just want this (I've corrected other potential issues in your code too):

```
public ActionResult GetSomething(int? id)
{
    String cacheFilePath = Path.Combine( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Cache" );
    FileCache cache = new FileCache( cacheFilePath, false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) );

    String cacheKey = String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "CacheKey{0}", id );
    if( purgeCache ) cache.Remove( cacheKey );

    String valueString = this.GenerateString( id );

    String myString = (String)cache.AddOrGetExisting( cacheKey, valueString, new CacheItemPolicy() { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(30) });
    return new JsonStringResult( myString );

}
```

1. C# Interpolated strings `$"like {this}"` are not suitable for use outside of UI code because they automatically use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which results in inconsistent output depending on the current thread's culture which in ASP.NET is automatically set to the visitor's browser's `Accept-Language` header value. It's best to use an explict `String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, format, args )` instead.
2. Your code had redundant steps for generating the cache key, I moved it to a single variable `cacheKey` instead.
3. C# naming conventions use `camelCase` for parameters and locals, and `PascalCase` for methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem however appears to be that without the delegate/callback function, GenerateString() is called every time.     `String valueString = this.GenerateString( id );` will be executed regardless of whether the cache entry exists or not this way.

Comment: Evk found out why it wasn't working; still your answer has helped me a lot. Thank you again.